# How can I directly boot into Ubuntu touch from my PC?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

As the x86 version of Ubuntu touch exists, I like to directly boot into Ubuntu touch (may be from my pen drive) for testing purposes.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question might be found at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install.  If you boot from a live CD, and make all the modifications on that device, it should become what you are looking for.